# Need Some Input on Right Licensing Path

Tags: licensing, desktop-application, putty

So I am almost finished with my first app. It was constructed in Visual Studio/C#. I am now trying to determine which license to run with. I plan to provide the program free of charge to businesses and consumers, however, I do not want to publish the source code.

What is the best licensing format to go with? This application is kind of a teaser for a more powerful version so I would like to publish this one for free and hopefully make some money selling the 'power user' version.

I will be packaging Putty with this. I am about to go read their site as I may need to role my own SSH client.

I will be headed to my lawyer this week. Just want to get a bit of knowledge before I talk to her so I don't look like a dumb fool. Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: Putty uses MIT so it shouldn't matter at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty uses the [MIT licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License), so all you need to do is incorporate that licence along with your software. For your code you can use whatever licence you choose, no one will ask for your code unless you explicitly want to make it public.

Comment: Does this mean I could use the MIT license myself?

Comment: Yes, you can use the `MIT` licence. You are not obligated to provide the source and you can sell your binary application.